# The LHR site says that a visitor may get a 24-hour visa on arrival at the discretion of the immigration officer. Is this still (January 2018) true?

Tags: visas, uk, transit-visas, layovers, lhr

My friend, an Indian national, will be kicking her heels in LHR, for a long layover. If possible, I'd like to meet up with her. This would require her to clear immigration and enter the UK. [The LHR website](https://www.heathrow.com/arrivals/immigration-and-passports) mentions a 24-hour visa available at the discretion of the immigration officer.

She meets the onward travel requirements, but does not have any UK visa.

I can't find any mention of this 24-hour visa on any government web sites.  Does anyone know if it really works? Is there a fee and how much?

Comment: Where is your friend travelling from and to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If she is:

- traveling to another country with enough funds and proof to be able to enter that country.
- able to show that her only purpose is transit while leaving the airport
- leaving the UK within the next 48 hours

she can get a [visitor in transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa). She can also get this visa if she is traveling to/from or has a visa/permanent residence of USA, Canada & a couple of other [countries](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes).

Technically you can get this visa on-arrival at the airport as long as the immigration officer is satisfied with the mentioned conditions.

However, if you are not sure about it you can [apply](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa) for it beforehand. The fee is 62 pounds.

PS: As far as I know the 24-hour direct airside transit visa (DATV) is if you won't leave the airport.

Answer (score 2):

Check this pages:

[Visa to pass through the UK in transit](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa)

But, according to this site, your friend may need a Visitor in Transit visa instead.